# How can we used tables in react.js pdf file

Tags: reactjs, pdf, document

I am downloading `pdf` file through `react.js`. I want a static table in `pdf` file but i can not. How can i add table in `pdf` HTML using `react.js`. is there any way to add tables in `react.js`. How can i implement table into a `pdf` document file. please help me to solve this problem. I will be very 
thankful.

Here is the code of my PDF document file which i am rendering.

```
import {
 Table,
 TableBody,
 TableHeader,
 TableHeaderColumn,
 TableRow,
 TableRowColumn,
 } from 'material-ui/Table';

<Table>
  <TableHeader>
    <TableRow>
     <TableHeaderColumn>ID</TableHeaderColumn>
     <TableHeaderColumn>Name</TableHeaderColumn>
     <TableHeaderColumn>Status</TableHeaderColumn>
  </TableRow>
</TableHeader>
<TableBody>
  <TableRow>
    <TableRowColumn>1</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>John Smith</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>Employed</TableRowColumn>
  </TableRow>
</TableBody>
```

Answer (score 1):

PDF File can not read external css. Its read only **Inline CSS**. You are using react material. Its calling an external css. So PDF not affecting the designs. Try to write css in inline.

Comment: Where is the table in this file. i am also using same library. how can we import table in this library? @velusamy